# RSpec running error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Doing my first RSpec test and getting an error when I run:

```
 rspec spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb
```

error message:

> /Users/waymond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.14.7, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.13.1. Prepending`bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

In my Gemfile.lock, I noticed that there were 2 rspec-core's in there and one was 2.13.0, which might be the problem. Any help on how to go about fixing this is much appreciated. Thank you! Here is my Gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:           https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

 group :test, :development do
 gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.13.1"
 end

 group :test do
 gem "capybara", "2.1.0"
 end
```

and my Gemfile.lock:

```
  GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
  actionmailer (4.0.2)
  actionpack (= 4.0.2)
  mail (~> 2.5.4)
  actionpack (4.0.2)
  activesupport (= 4.0.2)
  builder (~> 3.1.0)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
  rack (~> 1.5.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
  activemodel (4.0.2)
  activesupport (= 4.0.2)
  builder (~> 3.1.0)
  activerecord (4.0.2)
  activemodel (= 4.0.2)
  activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
  activesupport (= 4.0.2)
  arel (~> 4.0.0)
  activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
  activesupport (4.0.2)
  i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
  minitest (~> 4.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
  arel (4.0.1)
  atomic (1.1.14)
  builder (3.1.4)
  capybara (2.1.0)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
  nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
  xpath (~> 2.0)
  coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
  coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
  diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  erubis (2.7.0)
  execjs (2.0.2)
  hike (1.2.3)
  i18n (0.6.9)
  jbuilder (1.5.3)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
  multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
  jquery-rails (3.0.4)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
  json (1.8.1)
  mail (2.5.4)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
  mime-types (1.25.1)
  mini_portile (0.5.2)
  minitest (4.7.5)
  multi_json (1.8.2)
  nokogiri (1.6.1)
  mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
  polyglot (0.3.3)
  rack (1.5.2)
  rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
  rails (4.0.2)
  actionmailer (= 4.0.2)
  actionpack (= 4.0.2)
  activerecord (= 4.0.2)
  activesupport (= 4.0.2)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.0.2)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
  railties (4.0.2)
  actionpack (= 4.0.2)
  activesupport (= 4.0.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
  rake (10.1.1)
  rdoc (3.12.2)
  json (~> 1.4)
  rspec-core (2.13.1)
  rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
  rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
  rspec-rails (2.13.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
  sass (3.2.13)
  sass-rails (4.0.1)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
  sdoc (0.3.20)
  json (>= 1.1.3)
  rdoc (~> 3.10)
  sprockets (2.10.1)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
  sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  sprockets (~> 2.8)
  sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  thor (0.18.1)
  thread_safe (0.1.3)
  atomic
  tilt (1.4.1)
  treetop (1.4.15)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
  turbolinks (2.1.0)
  coffee-rails
  tzinfo (0.3.38)
  uglifier (2.4.0)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  json (>= 1.8.0)
  xpath (2.0.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.3)

 PLATFORMS
 ruby

 DEPENDENCIES
 capybara (= 2.1.0)
 coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
 jbuilder (~> 1.2)
 jquery-rails
 rails (= 4.0.2)
 rspec-rails (~> 2.13.1)
 sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
 sdoc
 sqlite3
 turbolinks
 uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the spec using

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb
```

This will ensure the command is executed with the same version listed in your Gemfile.

It's likely you have more than one `rspec` versions installed on the system. Using `rspec` command directly will load the latest, but this conflicts with the version listed in your `Gemfile`.

Other possible solutions are:

- uninstall all versions except the one listed in the Gemfile
- upgrade the `rspec` version in the Gemfile

Comment: Thank you, Simone! Worked right away. I should of thought to update it . Rookie over here lol.

Comment: After above command: `Could not find gem 'puppet-lint-leading_zero-check (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by using a different RVM gemset.

I created a new gemset just for this Rails app and then ran bundle install. Then everything worked properly.

```
$ rvm gemset create app_name_here
$ rvm gemset use app_name_here
$ bundle install
```